# How I need to use geo_point type with Chewy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, chewy-gem

§Hi guys,
i have problem with `geo_point` type definition

My Chewy Index code:

```
class CoordinatesIndex < Chewy::Index
    define_type Coordinate.includes( :location ) do
        field :location, type: 'geo_point'
        field :user_id, type: 'integer'
        field :start_at
        field :finish_at
        field :created_at
    end
end
```

Also I have relation coordinate has_one location, location belongs_to coordinate.

Location model fields:
`lat`, `lon`

Error tha i get:

`{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse field [location] of type [geo_point]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"parse_exception", "reason"=>"field must be either [lat], [lon] or [geohash]"}}`

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For future Googler's, this is works fine:

```
field :location, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ { lat: location.lat, lon: location.lon } }
```

instead of

```
 field :location, type: 'geo_point'
```